# Block removal of account team members on owner change via UI

Tags: trigger, account, account-teams

I know this question has been asked before, but there has been nothing recent since the recent Winter 20 Account Team enhancements - [Customize Account Teams to Enhance Team Selling](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_networks_sales_features_core_account_teams_customizable.htm)

I recently created a trigger that blocks deletion of any account team member, which works great in every instance except when someone changes an account owner but does not check the "Keep account team" checkbox.  I don't understand why a trigger wouldn't apply in this instance, but it doesn't.  Any ideas on how to prevent the account team from being removed on account owner change?  Anything recent that would help with the Winter 20 release?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers don't automatically cascade when you update a parent record, which is why your trigger doesn't work. As far as I'm aware, the only solution would be to add an account trigger to copy the account team back on to the account when the owner changes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply.  Are you saying that the account team member triggers don't run if the update is on the parent record, e.g. the account?

Comment: @jameskbw Correct.